# Oberservable returning undefined

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I having issue with signing in a user. What I am working with is nativescript-angular with a rails 5 api running devise_token_auth for authentication. What's really strange is that in the server logs, it shows the request being completed and returning a 200 status. Moreover, it appears that either the observable itself or the map function returns undefined and I'm not sure why. If anyone can take a look that would be awesome.

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { Response, Http, Headers, RequestOptions, } from '@angular/http'
import * as Toast from 'nativescript-toast'
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
// import 'rxjs/add/Observable/throw'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  signinUser(signInData: { email: string, password: string }): Observable<Response> {
    let headers = new Headers;
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })
    let url = 'backend api'

    return this.http.post(url, signInData, options)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        let body = res.json()
        console.log("body: " + body)
        console.log('status: ' + res.json().status)
        Toast.makeText('status: ' + res.json().status).show();
        console.log('statusText: ' + res.json().statusText)
        Toast.makeText('statusText: ' + res.json().statusText).show();
        return body || null
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return Observable.throw(error)
      })
  }
}
```

signin.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router'
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, AbstractControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http'
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service'
import * as Toast from "nativescript-toast";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.css']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {
  signinForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private http: Http,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
              private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signinForm = this.fb.group({
      'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email,
                                      Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}")]),
      'password': new FormControl(null, Validators.required) 
    })
  }

  onSignin(form: any) {
    const email = form.email
    const password = form.password

    this.authService.signinUser({ email, password })
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {
          if(res.statusText == 'OK') {
            this.router.navigate(['movies'])
          } else {
            console.log(res.status + ' FAILURE')
            Toast.makeText(res.status + ' FAILURE').show();
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          Toast.makeText(error.message).show();
        },
        () => { 
          console.log('IN SUBSCRIBE') 
          Toast.makeText('IN SUBSCRIBE').show();
        }
      )
  }
}
```

EDIT 1

Heres the contents of the console

```
JS: body: [object Object]
JS: status: undefined
JS: statusText: undefined
JS: undefined FAILURE
JS: IN SUBSCRIBE
```

Comment: What does all those console logs say? Does the backend return a json object?

Comment: yeah please share the console error message which you are getting from browser.

Comment: The contents of the console.log's have been added as an edit.

Comment: When you log the response body you are getting an object. Please debug the application or use chrome inspector to view the object's properties. Maybe your data is available in a nested object inside of your body.

Comment: Clearly the response don't have a status. console.log('%O', body) to show the object fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what's happening:

When you call .json() on a response, it takes the body of the response and calls JSON.parse() on it and returns that value to you. So things like the response status and statusText are not in the value you get back from json(), only the actual json response body is there.

If you want to access those things, just get them from the response object directly in your service like this:

```
return this.http.post(url, signInData, options)
  .map((res: Response) => {
    let body = res.json()
    console.log("body: " + body)
    console.log('status: ' + res.status)
    Toast.makeText('status: ' + res.status).show();
    console.log('statusText: ' + res.statusText)
    Toast.makeText('statusText: ' + res.statusText).show();
    return body || null
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    return Observable.throw(error)
  })
```

}

as for in your component, you should structure it so that your component doesn't need to be concerned with things like response statuses.  that's a service level task, if it's not what it needs to be, then use Observable.throw() to make sure it goes to the component error handler.  Worth mentioning though that if the http service gets any kind of error response, it will go to the error handler anyway without you needing to intervene.

Also this piece:

```
.catch((error) => {
   return Observable.throw(error)
})
```

is totally pointless unless you removed some code for the sake of SO. All you're doing is rethrowing the error.